# Is it possible to show a userform then continue to run a macro without further input

Tags: vba

I have a userform that has a number of Textboxes, one of which is for a date. This textbox can only be completed using a 'datepicker' userform to ensure consistent date format. I want to load and show the 'datepicker' when the destination userform opens so that the user doesn't have to click to invoke it.

I can do this by using the Userform_Initialize event but, then, the destination userform doesn't show until the 'datepicker' closes and I want the destination userform showing beneath the 'datepicker'.

I know that I can get the desired result by running the destination userform non-modally... but... it is called from another 'menu' userform which runs modal.

So... I guess the question is... Is it possible to show a userform and continue running the macro if the userform is shown modally?

RannochRob

Comment: Short answer: No.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use the Initialize
Simple Example to play with
To Show the other userform at the start example:
UserForm1
UserForm2

in UserForm1:

```
Option Explicit
Dim activated As Boolean


Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
If activated Then Exit Sub
activated = True
UserForm2.Show vbModal

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
activated = False
End Sub
```

This will open Userform2 -> Your Datepicker -> and returns to UserForm1 when UserForm2 is closed.

To Test it put a TextBox1 in Userform1 and a CommandButton1 in UserForm2 and in UserForm2 the Code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
UserForm1.TextBox1.Text = "Hello World"
Unload Me
End Sub
```

And then start Userform1

Comment: That will only work if you use the [default instance of the userform](https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/userforms_advanced_tips.html)

Comment: @Storax I kept it as simple as possible. And normally I would send the textbox as argument to a public sub in Userform2 and in this sub I would view the UserForm2 but my experience tells me - K.I.S.S.

Comment: I am just saying ;-)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I worked it out...

The answer is basically to run all three userforms non-modaly.

The issue I had when I first tried this was that the 'initialize' event was triggering as soon as the 'userform' was loaded and before it was 'shown'.

This meant that a) the second userform didn't show until the third userform (datepicker) was dismissed and b) changes that were made to the second userform by the 'click' event in the ControlButton on Userform 1 (The Menu Form) were also not being actioned until 'datepicker' was dismissed.

Once I worked that out, I realised that the answer was to simply move the code that changed the second userform from the 'click' event on the 'menu Form' to the 'Initialize' event on the second userform. Issue solved.

Thanks to those who replied.

RannochRob